# Удалить из строки все символы, заключенные в скобки

Tags: python

Например, для строки "abcd(123)efg" удалить подстроку "123" и получить в результате "abcdefg". Нужно удалить не только скобки, но и символы, которые внутри них.

```
my_string = input()
result_string = ""
a=my_string.find('(') 
b=my_string.find(')')
```

Comment: А спросить у ChatGPT?  он такие задачки на раз решает

Comment: А если есть вложенные скобки? А если скобки некорректно открываются/закрываются?

Answer (score 0):

воспользуемся срезом строк

```
my_string = 'aaa(ssssss)bbb'#input()

a=my_string.find('(')
b=my_string.find(')')

result_string = my_string[0:a] + my_string[b+1:len(my_string)]
print(result_string)
```

результат

```
aaabbb
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями

```
import re

txt = 'abcd(123)efg'
out = re.sub(r'\([^)]*?\)', '', txt)
print(out)
```

```
abcdefg
```